# Javascript: Check item status in another array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two arrays, array "A" has a column called "deleted" and a column called "rcCode". Array "B" just has column "cegCode" that matches up with "rcCode" in array A.

I want to check if the items in array B are deleted according to the information in array A.

```
A = [
  {"rcCode":"ABC", "deleted":"1"},
  {"rcCode":"DEF", "deleted":"0"},
  {"rcCode":"GHI", "deleted":"1"},
  {"rcCode":"JKL", "deleted":"0"}
];
B = [
  {"cegCode":"DEF"},
  {"cegCode":"GHI"}
];
```

In short, need to check if each item in "B" has a deleted status in "A"

Comment: Why the downvotes? An explanation would be good so I can make sure to improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. For first check which items are included in the array `A` according to array `B` using [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Then when you get the appropriate data, use [**Array#every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if for all items the condition is true - `deleted === 1`.

```js
const A = [
  {"rcCode":"ABC", "deleted":"1"},
  {"rcCode":"DEF", "deleted":"0"},
  {"rcCode":"GHI", "deleted":"1"},
  {"rcCode":"JKL", "deleted":"0"}
];
const B = [
  {"cegCode":"DEF"},
  {"cegCode":"GHI"}
];

const result = A.filter(item => B.some(i => item.rcCode === i.cegCode))
                .every(item => item.deleted === 1);

console.log(result);
```